# При нажатии на кнопку одно окно закрыть и программа должна перейти к другому окну

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Друзья, возможно задаю глупый вопрос, я новичок, пытаюсь разобраться с GUI. 
Есть такой код:

```
from tkinter import *
from idlelib.tooltip import Hovertip

def okno2():
    ak = Tk()
    ak.title(“Окно 2”)
    ak.geometry(“150x80”)

    btn = Button (ak, text=“Окно2”, height = 4, width = 20)
    btn.pack(side=LEFT)
    Hovertip(btn, )
    tk.mainloop()

tk = Tk()
tk.title(“Окно1”)
tk.geometry(“100x80”)

btn = Button (tk, text=“Старт”, height = 4, width = 20, command = okno2)
btn.pack(side=LEFT)
tk.mainloop()
```

Суть вопроса такая: что нужно сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Старт окно 1 закрывалось и программа переходила к окну 2!

Заранее спасибо, буду очень благодарен!!!

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов

```
from tkinter import *


def okno2():
    tk.destroy()
    ak = Tk()
    ak.title("Окно 2")
    ak.geometry("150x80")

    btn = Button(ak, text="Окно2", height=4, width=20)
    btn.pack(side=LEFT)
    ak.mainloop()


tk = Tk()
tk.title("Окно1")
tk.geometry("100x80")

btn = Button(tk, text="Старт", height=4, width=20, command=okno2)
btn.pack(side=LEFT)
tk.mainloop()
```